# Android - navigation drawer navigationview bug: some non selected items are becoming bold

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigationview

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/colorMenuBg"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:maxWidth="268dp"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
    app:itemHorizontalPadding="28dp"
    app:itemIconPadding="18dp"
    app:itemIconSize="24dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_item"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_item">
```

Part of nav_menu:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_videos"
    android:icon="@drawable/cat_icon_videos"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:title="@string/all_videos"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_pics"
    android:icon="@drawable/cat_icon_gallery"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:title="@string/all_pics"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_gifs"
    android:icon="@drawable/cat_icon_gif"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:title="@string/all_gifs"/>
```

it's over 15 items

After selecting one item, the text of one or two unselected random items is becoming bold.

Any idea how to fix?

Maybe preventing it programmatically inside:

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_latest -> {
            if (currentGal != "latest") {
                getMemes("latest")
            }
        }
        R.id.nav_top -> {
            if (currentGal != "top") {
                getMemes("top")
            }
        }
        R.id.nav_random -> {
            if (currentGal != "random") {
                getMemes("random")
            }
        }
```

?

Thanks in adance